# .htaccess redirect wildcard - moving subdomain to different domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wildcard-subdomain

subdomain is unchanged:
loja

Old domain:
loja.**churrascoelareira.com.br**

new domain
loja.**bomdebrasa.com**

The thing is that google is still sending visitors to urls like this:
loja.churrascoelareira.com.br/exemple-product-page.html

How can I forward that to:
loja.bomdebrasa.com/exemple-product-page.html

with wildcards?

**EDIT1**:
The file is like the following (both domains point to the same server) and this file is located in tow folders (just to make sure): public_html and public_html/churrascoelareira.com.br

Bellow this code there is an image of the cPanel's parked domain.

```css
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# Google Analytics Integration - Added by cPanel.
<IfModule mod_substitute.c>
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute "s|(<script src='/google_analytics_auto.js'></script>)?</head>|<script src='/google_analytics_auto.js'></script></head>|i"
</IfModule>
# END Google Analytics Integration
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bomdebrasa\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.bomdebrasa\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.bomdebrasa\.com\/newsite\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bomdebrasa\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.bomdebrasa\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^site\/?$ "http\:\/\/bomdebrasa\.com\/newsite" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bomdebrasa\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.bomdebrasa\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^site\/produtos$ "http\:\/\/bomdebrasa\.com\/newsite" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^loja\.churrascoelareira\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://loja.bomdebrasa.com/$1 [R=301,QSA]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# NOTE this account's php is controlled via FPM and the vhost, this is a place holder.
# Do not edit. This next line is to support the cPanel php wrapper (php_cli).
# AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .phtml
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

cPAnel's parked domain:
[image]

**EDIT2**:
I finally found where (in this outdated cPanel version) to do the redirects with wildcards. So this is solved (not by manually creating the file, but solved) and I checked the .htaccess file that was already there and saw nothing new, so I guess it was done in another way.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "wildcard" here, but this rule setup should forward those requests to the new domain, if it is implmented in the *old* http host:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^loja\.churrascoelareira\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://loja.bomdebrasa.com/$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

For this to work you obviously need to have the rewriting module enabled and loaded *in the old http host*. The rule set will work likewise in the http server's host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess"), you should however prefer the first option. If you decide to use a dynamic configuration file then take care that it's interpretation is enabled for the old http host and that the file is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder and readable by the http server process.

Comment: I added that to the file in the edit. It is not working =(

At least not yet.

Comment: Well, what does that mean? Just a "does not work" does not really help. What happens to the requests? Do you get entries in the http servers error log file? Where is that file you mention located? Is it _really_ considered by the _old_ host name? This looks to be like a configuration file for the _new_ host...

Comment: Hey, @arkascha, I updated the question.

And thanks for your help :)

Comment: cPanel does not create dynamic configuration files, those create more problems that they solve, actually. Instead it changes the http servers host configuration where such rules belong anyway. So rules created that way are applied _before_ dynamic configuration files are considered.